# c++ accessing double array error working in c

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void fun(int** a){}
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n][n];
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Getting this error in C++, but it is working fine in C
but working for typecasted to (void*)a
and then converting to array=(int**)a:

```
test_.cpp:9:8: error: cannot convert
   ‘int (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)n) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’
to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void fun(int**)’
tried to pass a[][size] but size is not known
```

Comment: then how to pass a[n][n] to the function if n is taken from user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. One is in C, the other, C++.

**The C problem**:
Even in C, your multidimensional array `int a[n][n]` does not convert to an `int**`. There's a huge difference between ragged (or jagged) multidimensional arrays and contiguous multidimensional arrays. Ragged arrays are declared and allocated as

- `int ** jagged_array`
  A jagged array declared in this style can obviously be passed as an `int**` argument to some function; there's no conversion involved. With this type of array, the programmer must allocate (and eventually free) storage for an array of `int*` pointers to each of the rows in the array and must also allocate (and eventually free) storage for each of the array's rows.
- `int * jagged_array[size_spec]`.
  A jagged array declared in this style can also be passed as an `int**` argument to some function because of the way arrays decay to pointers in C (and C++). With this type of array, the programmer must allocate (and eventually free) storage for each of the array's rows.

Note that in both forms, there is an explicit place in memory for the `int*` pointers that point to the zeroth elements of the rows of the array. That is not the case with multidimensional arrays. A pointer to a row in a multidimensional array is computed, not stored. A multidimensional array declared as `int a[n][n]` cannot decay to an `int**`. It instead decays into an `int*[n]`. In C, a function that receives a variable length multidimensional array such as your `int a[n][n]` should be declared as `<return_type> fund (int n, int vla[n][n])`. (The array argument could also be specified as `vla[][n]`; the outer dimension is not needed.)

**The C++ problem**:
You are using variable length arrays. C++ does not support that C99 concept. That concept didn't exist in C with the original 1998 version of C++. The 2003 C++ standard was a minor revision to the 1998 C++ standard, so it didn't jump to C99. The authors of the most recent C++ standard, C++11, explicitly rejected supporting those C99 variable length arrays. You can't use variable length arrays in C++, at least not portably.

Answer (score 3):

Double arrays do NOT convert to double pointers.

Pass a double array to your function like so:

```
void fun(int arr[][5]);
```

Now it will work.

Answer (score 1):

When `T[N][N]` decays it turns into `T*[N]` for which there is no viable conversion when passing in the array.

Comment: i think fun(void* p) int** a=(int**)p works fine in this case

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the second dimension size when passing 2D array to functions. Otherwise, compilers cannot do addressing on the 2D array elements without knowing the size of second dimension.
Use

```
f(a[][5])
```

Comment: if a[n][n] where n is taken from user a is passed as its size is not known other than typecasting to (void*) is there any method to pass double arrays whose size is defined by user

Comment: but how come code is working fine in c can you eloborate mechanism in c